# How can i use it without one time binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, owl-carousel

Yesterday I find solution for my angular carousel, 
but its has some issue with binding.

Every time data of carousel should changing and now this example doesn't work , but when i add :: before openGame.availableMarketGroups in HTML ng-repeat , its works , but one time binding only .

How can i fix it ?
Any ideas ? 
Thanks

The source

```
VBET5.directive("owlCarousel", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.initCarousel = function(element) {
              // provide any default options you want
                var defaultOptions = {
                };
                var customOptions = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));
                // combine the two options objects
                for(var key in customOptions) {
                    defaultOptions[key] = customOptions[key];
                }
                // init carousel
                var curOwl = $(element).data('owlCarousel');
                if(!angular.isDefined(curOwl)) {
                $(element).owlCarousel(defaultOptions);
                }
                scope.cnt++;
            };
        }
    };
})
.directive('owlCarouselItem', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: false,
        link: function(scope, element) {
          // wait for the last item in the ng-repeat then call init
            if(scope.$last) {
                scope.initCarousel(element.parent());
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here is the HTML

```
<data-owl-carousel data-options="{navigation: true, pagination: false, rewindNav : true}">

    <div class="market-carousel">
       <div owl-carousel-item="" class="carousel-item" 
        ng-repeat="group in openGame.availableMarketGroups track by group.id">
            <span>...</span>
       </div>
    </div>

</data-owl-carousel>
```

Comment: what is in `openGame.availableMarketGroups`? you aren't showing that data here, but it is entirely what the question is about.....

Comment: @Claies its object data , i think main issue in directive , 

working example here plnkr
http://embed.plnkr.co/pOIh2mOkj9N5HajbiC9h/

Comment: the plunker you posted works just fine even when all the `::` are removed from the code, so it doesn't do anything to explain what you are asking about in the question.  "doesn't work" isn't really clear.

Comment: @Claies yeah , its working because data-binding is done , check please this plncr , remove :: and then add next number 
http://plnkr.co/edit/qAnXhA7yVyZDQUq6sXGY?p=preview

Comment: This question needs a better title.

Comment: Maybe :) any ideas ?